# Coverity Tool throws : Calling a method on null object java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()

Tags: java, servlets, classloader

Our legacy project is using  `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("some resource")` to find out some  URL.
Now coverity is throwing errors on ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() saying that it can be null.
Now, upon looking at the code of getSystemClassLoader(), it looks like in some scenario it can be null. And it is getting very complicated to understand the reason when it can be null.

My question is if an application has successfully started and is up and running, can still be there any chance that ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() can be null. Bcoz this method seems like it is used to start the java application.

can some one give an easy definition of the use of this method. I am not able to fully understand the java docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a resource from the system classloader, use [`getSystemResource(String name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResource-java.lang.String-).

So change the code as follows:

```java
// Before
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("some resource")

// After
ClassLoader.getSystemResource("some resource")
```

Comment: this is such a life savior answer, I could not have come up with that. Thanks @Andreas